# MYSQL query that shows most popular entry in a category

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a database that stores peoples interests I have a  query that goes through my interests table and lists the most popular interests based on the field categoryID. However all I can display is the categoryID and not the category name, how would I link in my table categories to show the category name and not the id?

This is my query and output:

PHP:

```
$interestCatPopular = "SELECT interest_desc, categoryID, MAX(num_in_cat) AS num_in_cat 
FROM
(
   SELECT interest_desc, categoryID, COUNT(categoryID) AS num_in_cat
   FROM interests
   GROUP BY interest_desc, categoryID
 ) subsel 
 GROUP BY interest_desc, categoryID";
 $mostPopularInterest = mysql_query($interestCatPopular) or die(mysql_error());

 $arrayResults = array();
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mostPopularInterest)) {
 $arrayResults[] = $row;
 }

 foreach ($arrayResults as $result) {
 echo "{$result['interest_desc']} was the most popular in category   {$result['categoryID']}    with {$result['num_in_cat']} occurrences\n";
 }
```

OUTPUT:

football was the most popular in category 9 with 10 occurrences goats was the most popular in category 4 with 1 occurrences Phil was the most popular in category 2 with 59 occurrences

Thanks

### UPDATE

table structure -
**interests:**

```
 Field  Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
interestID  int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT                          
name    varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci     No  None                                 
categoryID  varchar(30) utf8_general_ci     No  None                                 
interest_desc   text    utf8_general_ci     No  None                                 
date    timestamp           No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

**categories:**

```
Field   Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
categoryID  int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT                          
category_desc   varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci     No  None
```

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't you just join the two tables like this:

```
SELECT interest_desc, 
       (
         select categoryName 
         from categories where categoryID = subsel.categoryId
       ), MAX(num_in_cat) AS num_in_cat 
FROM ( 
      SELECT interest_desc, categoryID, 
      COUNT(categoryID) AS num_in_cat 
      FROM interests GROUP BY interest_desc, categoryID
) 
subsel 
GROUP BY interest_desc, categoryID
```

Comment: im getting a syntax error on your code (altered slightly) - $interestCatPopular = "
SELECT interest_desc, category_desc, MAX(num_in_cat) AS num_in_cat 
FROM ( 
      SELECT interest_desc, category_desc, 
      COUNT(categoryID) AS num_in_cat 
      inner join categories c on c.categoryID = categoryID
      FROM interests GROUP BY interest_desc, category_desc
) 
subsel 
GROUP BY interest_desc, category_desc";

Comment: @DIM3NSION Can you please post the tables structure??

Comment: Well, that's becouse there is no relarion bewteen the CategoryId column in itntrested table and the categories table. so I will update my answer to fit with your current table structure but it is highly recommended that you join the two tables with foreign key.